# PM2 - metric for ram usage? multiple metrics in one pmx.metric?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Can I place more than one metric in `const metric = pmx.metric`?

Is there a metric for ram as there is for cpu_usage? I tried the below but Memory usage is not showing:

```
let pmx = require('pmx').init({
  network: true,
  ports: true
});

let Probe = pmx.probe();

let errors = 0;

const metric = Probe.metric(
  {
    name    : 'Errors',
    value   : ()=> {
      return errors;
    } 
  },
  {
    name: 'Memory usage',
    value: ()=> {
      return memory_usage;
    } 
  }
);

function incrementErrorCounter() {
  errors++;
}

module.exports = incrementErrorCounter;
```

Comment: That is a good question, I've added an issue here: https://github.com/keymetrics/pmx/issues/94